# jQuery Tablesorter 2.10.8 - Dropdown Filter Breaks with Scroller Widget Enabled

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

### The Problem

I have been using the [Tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) plugin to make life better for end users. I have spent several hours trying to enable the 'scroller' and 'filter' widgets at the same time. **The problem is that when both are enabled the dropdown selectors fail to filter the table results.**

I have created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4ACj/1/) to illustrate the problem.

---

### The Workaround

(I think,) I have narrowed down the problem to a broken event listener on the `change` event of the dropdown selector.

According to the docs, [some methods](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#methods) are available for getting the current filters.

When I run:

```
$.tablesorter.getFilters( $('table') );
```

it returns an array of filter values; however, the dropdown selectors are always empty strings.

*On the other hand*, if I run:

```
$.tablesorter.setFilters( $('table'), [ 'Some Value', '', '', '' ], true );
```

then the filters will be updated and the table is filtered as expected.

I ended up making my own event listener, updating the filters, and searching with the new parameters.

```
$('someselector').on('change', 'select', function(event) {
    var table = $('sometableselector'),
        filters = $.tablesorter.getFilters( table );

    filters[Number($(this).attr('data-column'))] = $(this).val();
    $.tablesorter.setFilters( table, filters, true );
});
```

---

### The Question

Have I found a bug, or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.tablesorter.getFilters()` method doesn't know to look in the duplicated scroller header (created by the scroller widget), so that's why it doesn't work as you expect.

I guess you could call it a bug, since the `getFilters()` function isn't smart enough to check for duplicate headers. I went ahead and [added an issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/370), so I'll remember to fix it once I return from my sabbitcal.

Comment: Thanks for adding an issue. What do you think of my current workaround? Is this the best solution until you make the adjustments?